# Number of negative elements of a PSD matrix and its square root

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, positive-definite

Let us have a PSD matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and let us define the square root of this matrix as
$$A^{1/2} = V\times D^{1/2} \times V^{-1},$$
where $A=V\times D\times V^{-1}$ is the eigendecomposition of $A$ and $D^{1/2}$ is element-wise square root of matrix $D$ having eigenvalues of $A$ on its diagonal.

I would be interested, if there is something to say about the relation of $\textsf{nne}(A)$ and $\textsf{nne}(A^{1/2})$ where $\textsf{nne}(\cdot)$ stands for the number of negative elements of the matrix. Furthermore, is there something to say about the relation of maximum elements of matrices $A$ and $A^{1/2}$? I known that for any PSD matrix it holds that $|a_{ij}| \leq \max\{a_{ii},a_{jj}\}$, so it is sufficient to focus on diagonal elements only.

So far, my computational results for some randomly generated matrices suggest that $\max_{ij} A \geq \max_{ij} A^{1/2}$ and $\textsf{nne}(A) \geq \textsf{nne}(A^{1/2})$, at least when all eigenvalues of $A$ are $\lambda_i\geq1$, but even with $1\geq \lambda_i\geq0$ I was not able to produce counter example so far.

So is this in general true or is there some counter example to this?

**Update #1:**
As pointed out by Alex Ravsky in the comments, the inequality about maximum element fails for a diagonal matrix with all eigenvalues $<1$. So now the question is, whether this fact somehow transfers to the question about $\textsf{nne}(\cdot)$ or not. If yes, does the above hold at least for matrices with $\lambda_{min}\geq1$?

Comment: Notice that you can always bring all eigenvalues of a PD matrix to $\lambda_i\ge 1$ by multiplying for an apposite constant $c>\|A^{-1}\|$, without modifying $nne(A)$ and with a controlled behaviour of $\max A_{i,j}$

Comment: Indeed. It might simplify the further analysis...

Comment: partial answer: $A-A^{1/2}$ is still SPD, so its diagonal elements are nonnegative. In particular, $A_{i,i}\ge A^{1/2}_{i,i}$ for all $i$, so the maximum surely decreases

Comment: How do you prove that $A-A^{1/2}$ is PSD?

Comment: It seems when $A$ is diagonal, $\lambda=\max \lambda_i<1$, and $V=I$  then $D$ is diagonal and its maximal element is $\sqrt{\lambda}>\lambda$.

Comment: Indeed it is true. So it falsifies the claim at least about the maximum element. The question remains, if this fact affects $nne(\cdot)$ or not. Luckily, in my application I can ensure that eigenvalues are at least 1, so for me this case is of interest as well. So do the above inequalities hold for matrices with large enough eigenvalues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is equivalent to asking if for PSD matrices $A$, we have $nne(A^2)\ge nne(A)$. The answer is "certainly not always". Indeed, suppose it is the case. Then raising $A$ to high powers should result in more and more negative entries. However, those entries are just $(A^n e_i,e_j)=\sum_k\lambda_k^n\langle e_i,v_k\rangle\langle e_j,v_k\rangle$ ($n$ is a large power of $2$). Now choose the eigenvectors $v_k$ of $A$ so that $\lambda_1$ is the largest eigenvalue and $\langle v_1,e_j\rangle>0$ for all $j$. That still allows for negative entries if the dimension is not too small. However, in this case a sufficiently high power of $A$ will have all entries positive. For a particular example in $\mathbb R^3$, take $v_1=(1,1,1)/\sqrt 3$, $v_2=(1,-1,0)/\sqrt 2$ and $v_3=(1,1,-2)/\sqrt 6$ with $\lambda_1=1.1, \lambda_2=1$ and $\lambda_3=0.01$, say.

Comment: Thank you for very nice answer. Does this construction rely on having some eigenvalue smaller than 1, or this assumption can be lifted, e.g., based on Exodd comment?

Comment: @qmsource No. You can multiply $A$ by any number (say, $1000$) and it won't change anything.